# Compare Day images with Night images PILLOW python

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

Folks - I'm trying to compare the pictures taken during daytime with the pictures taken during night time, and will then, need to compare them. However, when I tried to do it, because of number of `white` pixels, the difference between the images are huge, even though the images exactly the same. Meaning, the presence of light is causing the program to think the images are different.

I'm using Pillow, and I tried various things such as applying a Gaussian Filter, converting the image to RGB with no success. My problem is, not having a lot of background in these things, I'm finding it hard to find a starting point.

Can you help?

Comment: What are you trying to detect as a difference, besides the dramatically changed lighting?

Comment: I'm trying to do detect motion, meaning if there is an object ( like a person ) in the frame.

Comment: This has to be done over much smaller time frame.  Or using known empty reference frames from similar lighting times.